# How to do hypothesis test between two different distributions?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I meet a practical problem: How to do hypothesis test between two different distributions, for example:

$H_0$: distribution is a normal distribution
$p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}\exp(\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}) $

$H_1$: distribution is Laplace distribution $p(x) = \frac{1}{2b}\exp(-\frac{|x|}{b})$

with $\sigma$ and $b$ fixed.

How can I construct some statistics to do hypothesis test? How to construct uniformly most powerful(UMP) test?

Right now, I only know how to do hypothesis test of same kind distribution with different parameters. In general, what's the procedure to do hypothesis test between two different kinds of distribution and construct some meaningful statistics and UMP? Can you please provide some references, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that $H_0$ and $H_1$ are not simple hypotheses and that values $\sigma$ and $b$ are not fixed constants?

Comment: @BotnakovN. Let's firstly take simple case: $\sigma$ and $b$ has been fixed. I meet a problem: given some data points with mean zero. And I know it's either normal distribution or Laplace distribution. I need to determine which one it is.

Comment: With $\sigma$ and $b$ known, you are going to be looking at $\frac1{2 \sigma^2}\sum x_i^2 - \frac1{b}\sum |x_i|$ and whether it is more or less than some value you can calculate that depends on $n,\sigma,b$ and your desired confidence.  But this will not work if  $\sigma$ and $b$ are unknown

Comment: @Henry Is it a good idea that just fix $\sigma$ and $b$ from population's variance? Then doing hypothesis test. Is there another framework which can work for non-fixed $\sigma$ and $b$. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sigma$ and $b$ are fixed constants, we have two simple hypotheses.

The best test (formally: the most powerful) in this situation is given by Neyman–Pearson lemma.

The optimal criteria has the next form: $$S = \{ x: \frac{p_{H_1}(x)}{p_{H_0}(x)} \ge c\},$$

where $c$ is a solution of the equation $\int_{S} p_{H_0}(x)dx = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the significance level.

References: Testing Statistical Hypotheses, Lehmann, or any book about statistics.